# How I can rebind a hot key in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods, minecraft-millenaire, minecraft-mods

I've installed some mods on my Minecraft 1.7.2, but they have a conflict: 1 key is used by 2 different mods. I can't rebind it, because it's happening on a server. Forge is giving a crash-report & stop.

Problem mods: millenaire & useful pets.

How can I rebind a key used by mods?

Comment: You should theoretically still be able to rebind it in your controls. Unless those two mods decided to do their own thing for keybinding. Which is not unlikely. Go to Settings->Controls and see if you can find the conflict (they should be highlighted in red)

Comment: I can think of no situation where forge CRASHES due to key binding conflicts. Crash Report: Or it didn't happen.

Comment: Key bindings aren't handled server-side, you should still be able to rebind them in controls. Plus a key conflict shouldn't be causing crashes.

Comment: Apparently Dradge is not satisfied with "You can still rebind it".

Comment: And I think "I can't rebind it, because it's happening on a server." is logical. Maybe the server itself is detecting when a player presses a button "say, `Y`" then it performs some actions. Example: You press `Y` and it gives you free steak. You can't rebind it as it's on server side. (Well, it's just a guess.)

Answer (score 1):

All mod keys should be in the Controls for mods loaded by Forge. Go to Settings → Controls and see if you can find the conflict. All conflicting keys are written in red instead of in normal white.

An alternative solution is to edit the mod itself. Open the mod in which the keys conflict in Eclipse ([YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ReBa0Eo0be4)), then locate the class that's named something like KeyPress.class, search for the key and change it there.

Comment: Editing the source code will (probably) make it multiplayer incompatible. Although, since it's only modifying a Keypress it may work, still wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Not all keybinds are shown in the controls menu. It its not shown in there, i think they're out of luck. I wouldn't start messing with the mod files either.